# Create a new docker image and capture external volume contents

Tags: docker, docker-volume, docker-container, docker-image

I have a docker container with a named volume that is mapped to storage its host.  On that storage are a collection of static files.  I'd like to create a new version of this image that 
doesn't map to a volume on the host and instead contains these static files inside the image.

Is there a simple way to capture the contents of the container + everything on the volume into a new image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of roundabout way, you can use [docker volume backup](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) to export the data of the volume to a tar archive/plain copy(cp)/rsync to the host machine.

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from dbstore -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /dbdata
```

where `dbstore` is the container's name which has the mounted volume.

Then, you can extract the tar to get the contents in another folder.

```
tar xvf /backup/backup.tar
```

Then, create a Dockerfile whose base is the current image and COPY them into the new Image.